# Selenium, Python, problems with selecting specific Xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have the following issue. I am trying to scrape some information of a website. After a search query I get multiple results and I have to click on each result and copy some information out of it. Problem is, I can't / don't want to use static xpaths. They seem to break after a few searches.

[image: Picture of HTML]

Each child block does have a "data-index".
How can I specifically select the href underneath data-index="1" here?

I tried a few things but I came to no conclusion.

Comment: Can you post that as text instead of an image?

Comment: The text is rather messy with lots of long links and images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using

```
//div[@data-index='1']
```

to locate the web element like this :

```
first_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-index='1']")
```

Now `first_element` should represent the `data-index 1`.

You can call the `find_element_by_xpath` on this `first_element` **web element like this :**

```
href_link = first_element.find_element_by_xpath(".//descendant::a[@href]").get_attribute('href')
print(href_link)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply loop over `[class"row serp_a"]`

```
j=1
for links in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='serp_block']/div[@class='row serp_a']"):
      urls += '-'.join(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='serp_block']/div[@class='row serp_a'][%d]/div/a" % (j,)).get_attribute('href'))
      print(urls)
```

It will collect all urls under the div blocks you want. Is this helpful?